# Webhook service that buffers messages and is polled through HTTP streaming

Tags: webhooks

I need to interface a secure system that is situated in a protected LAN environment that absolutely must not expose any inbound tcp connections. Thus serving up an http server to provide a means to a webhook service to call as its callback is not an option.

I need to use a third party SMS provider to send and receive text messages. Receiving text messages is the problem.

So I've never really understand how so many services require their customers to provide a webhook. It's such a headache. Companies provide nice things like SDK. For example, when I want to send SMS messages using Twilio of Telnyx for example, I take their jar files, and basically just call a few methods and the SMS is sent without much fanfare. But the fun starts when I want process incoming SMS messages with those (and other) providers. They demand you host a webhook. So there are webhook providers that remove the pain of providing ways to fend of ddos attacks and other heinous scripting kiddies and whatnot, but then those webhook providers *still* require me to host an http server for it to drop its events to. Why can't I just keep a tcp connection alive to such a provider, and read from a connection that won't send data back until there is something to report, with a periodic heartbeat? And why can't companies like Twilio and Telnyx and others provide all this, without webhooks? It ought to be as simple as providing an event handler interface that simply gets called when needed. The customer shouldn't have to worry about anything more than just dropping in a library and providing a callback method, imo! It's completely feasible, yet it's not provided! Why?

So, because those companies are forcing me to provide a webhook, is there a webhook provider that *I* can keep a connection open *to*, where read request trickle out content as needed? A way where I do not have to host any http server?

Comment: I hate to just leave a link response, but there's not a lot of way around it here.
https://www.hostedhooks.com

Comment: Thanks James. I'm signing up and will see how this pans out.
ps. to anyone, this is *not* a plug or anything like that. I was genuinely stuck. I simply can not host an http server, and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: ... I tried to sign up twice. Got nothing in my email. I need to find a different service. Why is it so hard to provide something that doesn't involve push?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know anything more about that service than you do.  I just tried to sign up myself, and it seems like the approval process is manual so you probably won't get an email right away.  Here's another one, and looks like it's free up to 10,000 events per month: https://hookdeck.com

Comment: At first glance it's the same usual deal. You have to specify that darn endpoint URL again.... I'm looking for ways where I do not have to provide any http server. They're all making it so unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way around what you're trying to do.  You're right - tcp connections don't exist when it comes to SMS providers, so if it's not an option to host internally, I would setup something external, such as through Amazon EC2.  Depending on the throughput, you can keep it small enough to be free, or at least very cheap.

Comment: If you are looking for an open-source alternative you might want to take a look at https://www.hook0.com/

Comment: I ended up slapping together a webhook in nodejs and deploying it in a cheap VPS. Routing outbound sms through it also.
Created socket based command port. So connection is maintained to it, and send commands are issued and polling for events.
Funny how these SMS providers like Twilio and Telnyx and such don't provide a ready to deploy webhook in nodejs with a command port like this, all ready to go. Instead they have everyone invent their own solution.